# Filter Python list to remove similar values

Tags: python

So I have a list with around 100 float values between 0 and 1 , something like:

```
[0.642918256477056,
 0.6429182558639024,
 0.6429182466700671,
 0.6429182068585415,
 0.6429180997884363,
 0.6428178743476422,
 0.6428174651415239,
 0.6428167927406518,
... ]
```

What I need is a way create a more simple list, where values that are the same during 4 decimals are removed and only keep the first. For example: the number 0,6429... is repeated several times in this original list, I only need it once.

After this I still need to know which values (indexes) where removed so I can "remap" them. For example:

```
len(original_list) # Result: 100 | remap 0:1 range (index0 is 0, index 100 is 1)
len(filterted_list) # Result: 10
```

For example, if the index 5 of the filteres_list was index 80 in the original_list, I need to know that the original remapped value was 0.8.

Sorry if I can't explain this better, if you help me with the first part is already a good help. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a set and round:

```
li=[0.642918256477056,
 0.6429182558639024,
 0.6429182466700671,
 0.6429182068585415,
 0.6429180997884363,
 0.6428178743476422,
 0.6428174651415239,
 0.6428167927406518]

seen=set()
data=[]
for n in li:
    nr=round(n,4)
    if nr not in seen:
        seen.add(nr)
        data.append(nr)   # append n if you want the unrounded value

print data 
# [0.6429, 0.6428]
```

You can either append to `data` either `n` (unrounded) or `nr` the rounded value. The order will be maintained.

Comment: thanks for this. How can I keep track of the remaped value? For example, if the index 10 in the original list is now index 30 or the filtered list, how can I get that information? Here is what I am using to remap the original list to 0-1. "float( list.index(i) )/ float(len(list)-1)"

Comment: You can use `enumerate`

Answer (score 1):

A set is defined as a list of unordered collections of **unique** elements.

If the order is not a matter for you, simply use a set:

```
import math
filterted_list = set(round(x, 4) for x in original_list)
```

You can also implement a simple ordered set using this receipt:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694/

Which remembers the insertion order of the items.

Comment: I would suggest `filterted_list = list(set(original_list))`

Comment: @user1765661, then use the orderedset instead.

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of what you've seen with a simple dictionary.  Then filter with a function that checks whether or not something has been seen before, after rounding to 4 decimal places.

```
seen = {}

nums = [0.642918256477056,
 0.6429182558639024,
 0.6429182466700671,
 0.6429182068585415,
 0.6429180997884363,
 0.6428178743476422,
 0.6428174651415239,
 0.6428167927406518]

def filterFN(x):
   x = round(x, 4)
   if seen.get(x) == None:
      seen[x] = 1
      return True
   return False

filter(filterFN, nums)
```

Comment: I like this solution, though I'd use `seen = set()` and `if x not in seen: seed.add(x); return True`

Comment: It's amazing how many different approaches there already are here in the answers!   A matter of style I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

If order is important, use `groupby` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)):

```
from itertools import groupby, imap

l = [0.642918256477056,
     0.6429182558639024,
     0.6429182466700671,
     0.6429182068585415,
     0.6429180997884363,
     0.6428178743476422,
     0.6428174651415239,
     0.6428167927406518,]

print [x for x, _ in groupby(imap(lambda el: round(el, 4), l))]
>>> [0.6429, 0.6428]
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from set, you can use list comprehension as below:

```
d=[0.642918256477056,
 0.6429182558639024,
 0.6429182466700671,
 0.6429182068585415,
 0.6429180997884363,
 0.6428178743476422,
 0.6428174651415239,
 0.6428167927406518]
result=[]
[result.append('%.4f' % round(i, 4)) for i in d if '%.4f' % round(i, 4) not in result]
print result
```

Output:

```
['0.6429', '0.6428']
```

1. Go through individual elements
2. Round the elements to 4 decimals
3. Add to result if the value not found in result list

Comment: This is a correct solution, but it runs in O(n²) in the worst case while using a set runs in amortized(O(n))

Answer (score 0):

Using python 2.7 and numpy around function, result being a dictionary where number are keys and values the indexes

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np

def getData():
    data=[0.642918256477056,
     0.6429182558639024,
     0.6429182466700671,
     0.6429182068585415,
     0.6429180997884363,
     0.6428178743476422,
     0.6428174651415239,
     0.6428167927406518]
    return data




def main():
    index_data={}
    rounded_data=np.around(getData(),4)
    index=0
    for number in rounded_data:
        if not number in index_data:
            index_data[number]=[index]
        else:
            index_data[number].append(index)

        index+=1
    print index_data
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```